# Using Byte[] in delphi

Tags: c#, delphi, byte, arrays

I have a c# project which I am trying to convert into Delphi.

I have a function addcoord

```
public static byte[] addCoord(Coordinate C, int ID)
{
    //Create an empty array of length 10
    byte[] ret = new byte[10];

    ret[0] = Convert.ToByte(newClass.Add);
    ret[1] = Convert.ToByte(ID);
    ret[2] = BitConverter.GetBytes(C.X)[0];
    //High-Byte of uInt16 X
    ret[3] = BitConverter.GetBytes(C.X)[1];
    //Low-Byte of uInt16 Y
    ret[4] = BitConverter.GetBytes(C.Y)[0];
    //High-Byte of uInt16 Y
    ret[5] = BitConverter.GetBytes(C.Y)[1];
    ret[6] = C.Red;
    ret[7] = C.Green;
    ret[8] = C.Blue;
    ret[9] = C.Master;

    return ret;
}
```

is there any equivalent to this in Delphi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Delphi equivalent of `byte[]` in C# is `array of byte`.
You could either use it with a fixed size:

```
var
  buffer = array[0..9] of byte;
```

or with dynamic size

```
type
  TByteArray = array of byte;

function AddCoord(const C: TCoordinate; ID: integer): TByteArray;
begin
  SetLength(Result, 10); 

  Result[0] := C.Red; 
  Result[1] := C.Green; 
end;
```

For some basic types there are also predefined array types which should be preferred to use. For example `TBytes`.

Generics have been introduced in Delphi 2009. If you are using at least this version you should prefer to use `TArray<T>`. For example `TArray<integer>` or `TArray<TMyType>`.

Comment: Delphi has built-in type `TBytes` for dynamic array of bytes, no need to introduce a user type `TByteArray = array of byte;`

Comment: Thanks. I just wanted to show how to create an array type on your own. But yes, you are right.

Comment: `TBytes` or `TArray<Byte>` will make it easier to interact with code from other libraries.

Comment: No, your example is very bad. Open arrays are very useful. They can accept static arrays and dynamic arrays. They are much more flexible. You do need to stop making inefficient copies though. Use `const`. And you can implement the open array version like this: `function Foo(const Arr: array of Integer): Integer; begin Result := Length(Arr); end;`

Comment: Fundamentally you are making the very common mistake of confusing an open array parameter for a dynamic array type. I removed that section of your answer because it was so misleading. Please do not restore it.

Comment: The point wasn't how to set the result of the method. I wanted to state that `array of integer` is not the same type as `array of integer` when it is defined a second time. That's a common mistake. I want the OP to know about that. That's why I made a parameter of type `array of integer` and a local variable of `array of integer` and tried to do an assignment. That assignment fails in Delphi but it doesn't fail in C#. Your edit removed that block. Obviously I didn't make it clear enough. How would you show an example of "How not to work with arrays"?

Comment: Please read my comments. It's not much fun repeating myself. The key is the difference between an open array parameter, and a dynamic array type. The syntax `array of integer` can be used to define either an open array parameter or a type. This has been discussed many many times here on SO, and elsewhere. Rudy's blog has a nice article on the topic.

Comment: [Open array parameters and array of const](http://praxis-velthuis.de/rdc/articles/articles-openarr.html).